# Downloaded malicious VSCode version

Tags: malware, windows

I just downloaded VSCode and after running the setup, which wouldn't give any response, I noticed that the setup.exe came from an obviously fake website. The website was the first to pop up upon entering 'vscode download' on google and looked exactly like the original website.

As hasty as I am, I didn't look twice and simply downloaded and executed the file (as administrator) on my Windows 10 machine. I'm not an expert in security, but basically I am now scared that this might have ruined my system (and even any devices connected to my network). Coincidentally, the website from which I obtained the setup immediately vanished (I still have the link but the website is gone), thus reconfirming that this must have been a setup.

Inspecting the setup.exe, it has about 700MB and the description says "shareIT" setup. As someone who is usually quite careful about cyber security, what would your best guess be on how to proceed? Is there any hope for my system or would you recommend flashing the whole drive? Are there any good procedures on checking if anything has been installed and, if so, on how to remove it? Windows defender and Malwarebytes do not seem to give any indication of anything going wrong.

Comment: welcome - you'll never know for sure, which is an argument for going over your host with a fine-toothed comb (at least) if not a full re-instal (only you can answer that);  (btw, it's *unlikely* that anything would've spread to other devices on your network, but that is going to depend entirely on what you have running and what can access it) .. at a minimum, give serious thought to installing a new browser from scratch (with a new profile), and also, have you checked the suspicious setup `exe` against https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload  ?

Comment: @brynk Thank you for your quick answer. I might go for a full reinstall at some point, as this definitely seems concerning. I gave virustotal a look and got three hits, including Trojan:W32/GenInflated.B from Acronis, Malware.SwollenFile!1.DDB4 (CLASSIC) from Kaspersky and HEUR:Trojan.Win32.Generic from Sophos

Comment: without having looked at what each one of those is capable of, it's  likely your host is compromised - that would be all the evidence i'd need to perform a full re-instal - power off your host os without delay in case ransomware is running, boot into a separate live usb system (eg. [knoppix](https://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html)) and perform a full snapshot backup of your work drive/s, and also optionally make separate file copies as well (the snapshot is the backup - the file copies are convenience for you after you've re-installed) ...

Comment: you might "get away with" restoring a savepoint, however, this won't help if the boot process has been interfered with to ensure continued re-infection (personally, i wouldn't take the chance) - [you used to be able to use an offline scanner](https://www.putorius.net/install-configure-and-scan-for-viruses-on-linux-with-clamav.html) such as [clamav](https://docs.clamav.net/) to do a scan of the offline windows drive/s from within linux .. after, boot safe-mode and use [`autoruns.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to ensure nothing is set to run at start up

Comment: ps. any network credentials (eg. wifi or vpn pre-shared keys, or eg. ssh private keys) and passwords that were stored on the old windows instance **must** be changed as a precautionary measure .. now that i say it out loud, i would prioritise this if any of those cred's were somehow crucial to you (or your reputation), eg. if they gave access to financial systems, or were work- or income-related

Comment: If you've been compromised, wipe your entire drive and install from scratch from a known to be clean source. Consider all your passwords and access tokens burnt. Change them all. Next time right click the exe and check its signatures. Run it through https://www.virustotal.com as well. I use this website for everything I download from the net. I even check microsoft.com downloads just in case. Nowadays it's better to be safe than sorry.